# coldfusion create list from query results

Tags: sql, binding, coldfusion

I am currently using Binding to grab values from a database. Depending on what the user selects from a pull down it shows the results from the database. Currently I am able to show one result but I need to show multiple results if the query brings back more then 1 value. Here is my current code.

```
<cffunction name="getServiceType" access="remote" returnType="array">
<cfargument name="CATG_NAME" type="string" required="true">

<cfset var data="">
<cfset var result=ArrayNew(2)>
<cfset var i=0>

<cfquery name="getServiceType" datasource="#dsource#">
select distinct SRTY_NAME
from Somedatabase
where (CATG_SPRS_NAME = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.CATG_NAME#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> OR CATG_DEPT_SPRS_NAME = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.CATG_NAME#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">)  AND EVLN_REQD_FLAG IS NOT NULL
order by SRTY_NAME
</cfquery>


<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#getServiceType.recordcount#">
<cfset result[i][1]=getServiceType2.SRTY_NAME[i]>
<cfset result[i][2]=getServiceType2.SRTY_NAME[i]>
</cfloop>

<cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

This generates the 1st pull down list

```
<cffunction name="getUnion" access="remote" returnType="array">
<cfargument name="SRTY_NAME" type="string" required="true">

<cfset var result=ArrayNew(1)>

<cfquery name="union_rq" datasource="#dsource#">
select U.UNI_NAME, S.SRTY_NAME
from Somedatabase U JOIN Someotherdatabase S ON U.SRTY_NBR = S.SRTY_NBR
where S.SRTY_NAME = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.SRTY_NAME#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>

 <cfset result[1]=union_rq.UNI_NAME>

 <cfreturn result>
 </cffunction>
```

The first list would have an option list Hotel Training and the second query should show both Maids and Cooks. Right now it only shows Maids. I tried to create a list or another array but have not be able to get it to display the results. Below is my Coldfusion call for the display. It is fine to display with commas between the results like Maids,Cooks

```
 <tr id="union">
   <td></td>

   <td>Union Attached:
   <cfinput name="uni_name"
   bind="cfc:servicetype.getUnion({service_type})"
   bindonload="false"
   /></td></tr>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreicated.

Comment: If you return a query on the cf side, and use cfselect or cfgrid, you can see a list of results.

Comment: Are you attempting to display multiple values inside a single text box?

Comment: Not related to your question, but in your functions, you should var your query names.  They are ColdFusion variables.

Comment: rather than `<cfset result[1]=union_rq.UNI_NAME>` do `<cfset result[1] = valueList(union_rq.UNI_Name)>` that will return a list of all the values in the query. Use `quotedValueList` if you want quotes with it